Keyboard not appearing after swipe-back gesture when returning to a screen with TextField using GetX
I'm developing a Flutter application using GetX for state management, and I'm facing an issue where the keyboard does not appear when returning to a screen with a TextField after navigating away and then using the swipe-back gesture to return.
Steps to Reproduce:
Open a screen with a TextField (e.g., a chat screen).
Tap on the TextField to ensure the keyboard appears.
Navigate to another screen (e.g., a profile screen) by tapping an element such as a profile image.
Use the swipe-back gesture to navigate back to the previous screen (e.g., the chat screen).
Tap on the TextField again.
Expected Behavior:
The keyboard should appear when tapping on the TextField after returning to the screen.
Actual Behavior:
The keyboard does not appear when tapping on the TextField after using the swipe-back gesture to return to the screen.
Code Example:
Here is a simplified version of the chat and profile screen implementation using GetX:
main.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'chat_screen.dart';
import 'profile_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: ChatScreen(),
    );
  }
}

chat_screen.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'profile_screen.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    _controller.dispose();
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      _focusNode.requestFocus();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Chat"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            onPressed: () {
              Get.to(() => ProfileScreen());
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          controller: _controller,
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Type a message",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


This issue occurs consistently when using the swipe-back gesture to navigate back to any screen with a TextField. The keyboard functions normally if I use the back button instead of the swipe-back gesture. I'm using GetX with GetMaterialApp.
How can I ensure the keyboard reliably appears for input fields after navigating back to a screen using the swipe-back gesture with GetX?
What I've Tried:

Using WidgetsBindingObserver to listen to app lifecycle events and refocus the FocusNode.
Using didChangeDependencies to refocus the FocusNode when dependencies change.
Manually calling FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode) in various lifecycle methods.


The github related issue 148867.
If you wanna stay in stable channel, you have to downgrade to 3.19.6.
It seems like stable version is not stable anymore.
update:
flutter 3.22.2 has solved the problem.

In the TextField, set autofocus to true. Navigating between screens can potentially cause the TextField to lose focus.

The keyboard does not appear when tapping on the TextField after using the swipe-back gesture. Focus is working but keyboard does not appear.

Downgraded to flutter v3.19.6 and it works now :)
